# REST API naming convention for search parameter

Tags: rest, naming-conventions

I need to format the RestAPI for my application. This API filters data on the basis of the search query parameters. I need to understand what is the proper format to handle the keys of the search query parameters in terms of the naming convention(camelCase/snake-case)

***Following is only a hypothetical example. I am focussed to finding the exact case that is followed for the search parameters of the RestAPI***

-- Question 1: Which is the correct casing format to be used for the search query parameter keys when the key is a combination of multiple words. 
eg: which of the following are correct : `....?searchType=A` or `....?search_type=A`

-- Question 2: Suppose I have 5 search types and for each search type, there is a value to be searched for. So to send this value in the search query parameters there should be only one generic key of "value" or if I can use "a", "b" etc per search type.
eg:

Format 1 : `....?search_type=A&a=testvaluea`/`....?search_type=B&b=testvalueb`

Format 2: `....?search_type=A&value=testvaluea`/`....?search_type=B&value=testvalueb`

**I am pinning for format 1 cz of the following features:**

-- using "a" and "b" etc search parameters makes sure that for a particular search type we can expect a certain parameter.

-- should this be a bad approach as in various forms the data is sent in particular search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Which is the correct casing format to be used for the search query parameter keys

This is really just a matter of preference. I like camel case ("searchType") because I typically code in Java and Swift, and both use this convention. If you are using a language or platform that prefers snake case ("search_type"), you can certainly use that.

> Question 2

I would suggest format 1 ("search_type=A&a=testvaluea"). This makes it clear that the value of "a" corresponds to search type "A". If you use the more generic "value", how would you know which values to associate with each search type? Query parameter ordering is not always preserved by server frameworks, so "value=testvalueb" may not always immediately follow "search_type=B".

Answer (score -1):

REST *doesn't care* what spelling you use for your URI.

Information encoded into the URI is done at the server's discretion and for its own use.

> Which is the correct casing format to be used for the search query parameter keys when the key is a combination of multiple words

Whatever conforms to your local spelling conventions; it's just like a variable name in that respect.

> should be only one generic key of "value" or if I can use "a", "b" etc per search type.

Again, follow local convention.

When in doubt, keep in mind that the reference implementation of REST is the web.  When you are filling out a form on the web, you don't *care* what the variable names are.  The form tells you what the variable name is, and the browser completely automates the process for you.

Comment: "When you are filling out a form on the web, you don't care what the variable names are" - REST API consumers are developers, not end users, and DO care what the variable names are.